# Find The Number Of Permutation

Tags: permutations

I was solving one probability question, and to solve the problem I could relate it to binary and want solution.

The question was that in a fair toss repeated 10 times, what's the probability of 10th try to be the 5'th head.

I used brute-force and calculated it to  be 63/512. But I can only brute force for definite numbers. What if I get n and x. So my problem is as stated below.

For all possible combination of a $n$ -bit binary number to have $x $ number of 1's where $x < n$.

Any Helps Will be Appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of $n$-bit binary numbers with $x$ ones is given by the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

$$
\binom nx=\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}\;.
$$

Comment: Can I find a proof for it

Comment: @KishanKumar: You certainly can -- e.g. in the sections titled "Definition and interpretations", "Multiplicative formula" and "Factorial formula" in the article I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you switched from the specific question to a generalised one,
**you changed the question**. Look closely at them !

The specific question involves what is called a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), whose details you can look up.

However, as the name suggests, it is linked to the binomial distribution, and you can easily derive a formula. For your specific case, you need 4 heads in **9 tries** followed by a head, thus

$${9\choose4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^9\left(\frac12\right) = \frac{63}{512}$$

Comment: Are you referring that I did not considering the last event

Comment: No, no, last event *needs* to be considered, and I have also considered it. It is the final term $\frac12$ in my expression. What I was saying is that there is a difference between getting the 5th head **on** the 10th toss (concrete example of yours), and getting *5* heads **in** *10* tosses (akin to the general problem you posed)

Comment: I am solving the question as 4 heads in 9 tosses. And then multiplying it with 1/2 to get the actual answer

Comment: That is fine for the original question.

Comment: Is there any better approach

Comment: No. Why do you find it difficult ? You just make a commonsense modification to the binomial distribution.

Comment: I just changed the question from coin toss to binary numbers. So, its bit hard to explain to someone. For example, if it would have been rolling a dice